# UFT File system test

Tags: hp-uft

Im a rookie on HP UFT testing and work on a data migration project I would like to automate.

Every day, we get a set of folder and files syncronize from a vendor with a following syncronization report(.csv file).

I would really like to test if the actual .csv file containing a list of files updated in the filesystem exists.
I get the .csv file on a network share, I open it and see a list of files with
data paths, which should be used to (loop)search though the filesystem and check if the files is actually on the location. How do I do that with UFT??

Comment: Welcome. You´d need to do more of your own research using google and similar widely available info sources before asking. Instead of asking a "How do I do it"-question, please understand that this site is very competent on answering "Why doesn't this work (see my simple example that reproduces my problem)"-questions but usually ignores the former kind of question. As soon as the community sees how far you´ve researched by yourself, they can see what you are possibly doing wrong, and gladly will help you with by-the-example guidance.

Answer (score 1):

sample script to get all csv content and looping through content and verifying whether files exists or not.

```
filename = "C:\path\list.csv"

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set f = fso.OpenTextFile(filename)

    Do Until f.AtEndOfStream
      filepath=f.ReadLine 'assuming every line as file full path
      if FSO.fileexists(filepath) then
         print filepath & " file is avaialble"
         ' do your checks here
      else
         print filepath & " file is not avaialble"
      End if
    Loop

    f.Close
```